# Remove column lines from an HTML table

Tags: html

I am making a pdf with html and I want to remove the lines that the columns give in the html but I don't know how, here is my code and an image. Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoI26.png)

```
    <table border=1 cellspacing="1" align="Center" width="500"   style="font-size:10px; " border-style: none;> 
<tr align="Rigth">
    <td colspan="8" height="25" bgcolor="#A8D08D"><b>INFORME DE LABOR ACADÉMICA</b></td>
    
</tr>
<tr align="Rigth">
    <td colspan="1"  width="40"  border-style: none;
    border: 1px solid black;> <b>FECHA:</b></td>
    <td colspan="3">{FECHA} </td>
    <td colspan="1"  width="40"><b>SEMESTRE:</b></td>
    <td colspan="1">{SEMESTRE}</td>
    <td colspan="1"  width="40"><b>AÑO:</b></td>
    <td colspan="1">{AÑO}</td>
</tr>
<tr align="Rigth">
    <td colspan="1"  width="100"><b>DOCENTE:</b></td>
    <td colspan="7">{DOCENTE}</td>
</tr>
<tr align="Rigth">
    <td colspan="1"  width="40"><b>FACULTAD:</b></td>
    <td colspan="3">{FACULTAD}</td>
    <td colspan="1"  width="40"><b>PROGRAMA:</b></td>
    <td colspan="3">{PROGRAMA}</td>
</tr>
<tr align="Rigth">
    <td colspan="2"  width="40"><b>TIPO DE VINCULACIÓN:</b></td>
    <td colspan="7">{VINCULACION}</td>
</tr>
<tr align="Rigth">
    <td colspan="1"  width="100"><b>DEDICACIÓN:</b></td>
    <td colspan="7">{DEDICACIÓN}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try removing the (left/right)borders of the table cells

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td{
    border-left:none;
    border-right:none;
}
```

```html
<table border=1 cellspacing="1" align="Center" width="500"   style="font-size:10px; " border-style: none;> 
<tr align="Rigth">
    <td colspan="8" height="25" bgcolor="#A8D08D"><b>INFORME DE LABOR ACADÉMICA</b></td>
    
</tr>
<tr align="Rigth">
    <td colspan="1"  width="40"  border-style: none;
    border: 1px solid black;> <b>FECHA:</b></td>
    <td colspan="3">{FECHA} </td>
    <td colspan="1"  width="40"><b>SEMESTRE:</b></td>
    <td colspan="1">{SEMESTRE}</td>
    <td colspan="1"  width="40"><b>AÑO:</b></td>
    <td colspan="1">{AÑO}</td>
</tr>
<tr align="Rigth">
    <td colspan="1"  width="100"><b>DOCENTE:</b></td>
    <td colspan="7">{DOCENTE}</td>
</tr>
<tr align="Rigth">
    <td colspan="1"  width="40"><b>FACULTAD:</b></td>
    <td colspan="3">{FACULTAD}</td>
    <td colspan="1"  width="40"><b>PROGRAMA:</b></td>
    <td colspan="3">{PROGRAMA}</td>
</tr>
<tr align="Rigth">
    <td colspan="2"  width="40"><b>TIPO DE VINCULACIÓN:</b></td>
    <td colspan="7">{VINCULACION}</td>
</tr>
<tr align="Rigth">
    <td colspan="1"  width="100"><b>DEDICACIÓN:</b></td>
    <td colspan="7">{DEDICACIÓN}</td>
</tr>
```